# Java LinkedList Poll doesn't complete

Tags: java

I wrote the following snippet:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> a = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            a.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Size: " + a.size());
        for (int d = 0; d < a.size(); d++)      // d from 0 to 9
        {
            System.out.println(a.poll());
        }
        System.out.println("Another poll: " + a.poll());
        System.out.println("Remaining: " + a.toString());
    }
}
```

With the following output:

```
Size: 10
0
1
2
3
4
Another poll: 5
Remaining: [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Why does the first printing for-loop only print 0-4 even though the loop iterates through the full size of the LinkedList and therefore should print all of it's content?

Comment: Each turn through the loop, `d` increases and `a.size()` decreases. The loop stops when `d >= a.size()`. So you're counting in from both ends.

Comment: When you poll an element it gets removed from the list. Therefore the list's size gets smaller. Use `while(a.peek() != null)` instead of your for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, got it!
*a.size()* is being decremented everytime a is being polled, therefore d only increases to 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int d = 0, size = a.size(); d < size; d++) {
    System.out.println(a.poll());
}
```

*Note:*

```
for(x;y;z) {}
```

there're 3 parts:

`x` - calculate once at the beginning of the loop

`y` - calculate before each loop iteration

`z` - calculate after each loop iteration